# File consentform.html on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I can not translate the file `consentform.html` in Italian because every time I do the "build" of the application, Android Studio relocates the same original file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding a little more context about your issue. However, it looks like you're editing a generated file and you need to find the source file instead.

Comment: exact. unfortunately I do not know where to find the source file

Comment: I tried to look inside all the files of the APP project with the "texcrawler" software the text to be translated which is not found anywhere

Comment: in the "build" phase of an application automatically generated the file consentform.html (the file that shows the consent to privacy to manage advertising -admob-).
since the text is all in English, I translate the file into Italian, save it, I resume the "build" of the application but re-convert the file consentform.html in English.

Comment: try performing a search using your IDE/editor, to find some part of the text from that file, to see if you can spot the source file

Comment: Thank you very much for the help you have been trying to give to me. I solved by finding (through program textCrawler) the temporary file inside the folder ".grade>caches>transforms-1>etc. etc...."
thanks again for the help